# KB5034441 and changing the recovery partition starting offset in order to be able to enlarge it

Tags: windows-10, recovery

I was getting an error on Windows update (security update KB5034441 was failing with Retry...retry...retry...) and that led me to forum postings on the internet where people were saying it was because the recovery partition was too small and it needed to be made larger so  that it would have 250MB free space.

So I bought some partitioning software, shrank the main O/S partition by 300MB, and then, using the software's drag/drop GUI features, I repositioned the recovery partition leftward so it abutted the main O/S partition and then I pulled the recovery partition rectangle's right side over to the right, thereby enlarging it by 300MB to a total size of 826MB.  Now, in the Windows 10 disk management utility, it says the recovery partition is "healthy" and shows that it is 826MB in size.

But I've since seen other postings that say that Windows 10 recovery made a note of where the *original* recovery partition started on the disk, and that it has a different starting offset now.  Am I no longer able to recover the O/S if that should ever be needed?

P.S. Download error is still happening on the security update after partition resize, reboot, update troubleshooter run with fixes, and reboot.

[image: healthy recovery partition]

Comment: Note: There is very good free partitioning software to be found.

Comment: The one I bought was said to be free (in multiple forum postings) but turned out not to be so.  I had to register it to save my changes, and there was no free version option available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need to delete and recreate the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) partition. Microsoft has [an article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5028997-instructions-to-manually-resize-your-partition-to-install-the-winre-update-400faa27-9343-461c-ada9-24c8229763bf) on how to do this.

The process involves using native command-line utilities so there is no need to install any third party software. However, admin privilege is required so run Command Prompt as administrator. These instructions also assume that the WinRE partition is located after the OS partition, as is the case in this question.

## Resize OS and WinRE partitions

- Check the WinRE status with the command `reagentc /info`. Note the harddisk and partition numbers in the Windows RE location
- Disable the WinRE with the command `reagentc /disable`

### Shrink the OS partition (if required).

- Run `diskpart` to start the interactive diskpart utility
- List the disks with the diskpart command `list disk`
- Select the OS disk, with the diskpart command `sel disk <OS disk index>` where <OS disk index> is the harddisk from the Windows RE Location you got from the previous reagentc command
- List the partitions on the disk with the `list part` diskpart command
- Select the OS partition with the `sel part <OS partition index>` diskpart command where <OS partition index> is the OS partition you got from list part diskpart command in the previous step
- Shrink the OS partition with the diskpart command `shrink desired=250 minimum=250`

### Delete and recreate the WinRE partition

- Select the WinRE partition with the `sel part <WinRE partition index>` diskpart command. Where <WinRE partition index> is the partition you got from both the reagentc command and the list part command in diskpart
- Delete the WinRE partition with the diskpart command `delete partition override`

#### Create a new recovery partition.

- Check if the disk partition style is a GUID Partition Table (GPT) or a Master Boot Record (MBR).  To do that, run `list disk`. Check if there is an asterisk character (*) in the “Gpt” column.  If there is, then the drive is GPT. Otherwise, the drive is MBR

  - If your disk is GPT, run the diskpart command `create partition primary id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac` followed by `gpt attributes =0x8000000000000001`
  - If your disk is MBR, run `create partition primary id=27` instead
- Format the partition with `format quick fs=ntfs label=”Windows RE tools”`
- Confirm that the WinRE partition is created with `list vol`
- Exit from diskpart with `exit`
- Re-enable WinRE with the command `reagentc /enable`
- Confirm where WinRE is installed `reagentc /info`

On one of my Win 10 machines, I ended up with a recovery partition that was 781MB in size and this was sufficient to allow the successful installation of the Windows Update KB5034441.

Comment: We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please [do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless. Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source. Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Fair point. Edited to explain the steps from the docs

Answer (score 1):

> Windows 10 recovery made a note of where the original recovery partition started on the disk

I wonder where you found such text.

The recovery partition is identified by its partition-id. Whenever the
need arises to do the recovery, it will be located by this id.
Byte offsets to point to partitions is a thing of the past.

Assuming that your partitioning software did its task correctly,
you have nothing to worry about, especially if the Windows update
was successfully installed.

Comment: Thanks.  Windows update error still happening, unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, the recovery partition wasn't correctly enlarged. See this [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5028997-instructions-to-manually-resize-your-partition-to-install-the-winre-update-400faa27-9343-461c-ada9-24c8229763bf) and follow the instructions as much as required (for example you already did step 4).